# Compiling a haskell script with external dependencies without cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm relatively new to Haskell and I realize I might be swimming against the stream here, but nonetheless, I'll ask:

Say I have a short Haskell script:

```
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let orders = splitOn "x" "axbxc"
  putStrLn $ head orders
```

If I used only standard functions I could compile this with `ghc <script.hs>`. Because I depend on the `split` package to provide the `splitOn` function, the compilation fails.

Now, I have no difficulties setting up a cabal project with a `project.cabal` and a `Setup.hs` file in order to get this to actually compile. However, this feels like a lot of extra boilerplate for a standalone script.

So, **is there a way to compile a single .hs file against some external package?** Something similar to what in Python would be done by `pip install something`, "installing the package into the interpreter", i.e. is there a way to install extra packages "into ghc", so that I for instance only need to provide some extra linking flag to ghc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/), the simplest way to do this is to write a ‘Stack script’, which is a Haskell file with a description of the required packages in the first line (really an invocation of `stack` specifying the appropriate command line arguments). An example (slightly modified from [the docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter)):

```
$ cat turtle-example.hs
-- stack --resolver lts-6.25 script --package turtle
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Turtle
main = echo "Hello World!"
$ stack ./turtle-example.hs
Completed 5 action(s).
Hello World!
$ stack ./turtle-example.hs
Hello World!
```

This script uses the `turtle` package; when run, Stack downloads and builds this dependency, after which it is available in the script. (Note that the second time it is run, `turtle` has already been built so does not need to be rebuilt again.)

As it happens, the `--package` command in Stack is not limited to scripts. It can be used with other Stack commands as well! For instance, to compile your program, you should be able to run `stack ghc --resolver lts-16.27 --package split -- -ghc-options your-program-name.hs`. And `stack ghci --package split` will give you a GHCi prompt where you can `import Data.List.Split`.

(Note: This answer focuses on Stack rather than Cabal, simply because I don’t know Cabal very well. However, I believe all this can be done using Cabal as well. For instance, I do know that Cabal has something very similar to the Stack scripts I mentioned above, though I can’t remember the syntax just at the moment.)

**EDIT:** See [@duplode’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65541020/7345298) for how to do this with Cabal.

Comment: I have added the Cabal equivalent in [a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65541020/2751851).

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: Thanks @duplode! I’ll edit a reference to that into my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The Cabal equivalent of the Stack script in [bradrn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540046/2751851) would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env cabal
{- cabal:
build-depends: base
            , split
-}

import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let orders = splitOn "x" "axbxc"
  putStrLn $ head orders
```

The script can be run with `cabal run`, or directly by giving it execute permission. If need be, version bounds can be added as usual to the `build-depends` on the top of the script.

(Note this isn't literally a solution without Cabal, as doing this with GHC alone, even if it is possible, wouldn't be worth the trouble. In any case, it certainly avoid the boilerplate of needing multiple files.)

Answer (score 2):

You can install into the default environment for the current user by doing `cabal install --lib split`.  The package should then be available to ghc and ghci without needing any special options.

More information is at the bottom of [this section in the Cabal manual](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-commands.html#cabal-v2-install).  The `v2` commands that it uses are the default now so if you have a fairly new cabal you can just use `install` rather than `v2-install`.

Comment: Thanks, that is great to know! Probably the most direct answer to my original question, even though I now prefer the stack-based answer for its reproducibility. But very glad to have learned about this, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the quintessential entry point to the package management battle in Haskell. It's not there's not enough advice, but there's so much, each with its own caveats and assumptions. Climbing that mountain for the sake of `splitOn` feels to the newbie like they're Doing It Wrong.

After spending far too much time trying each permutation, I've collated the fine answers here, and many, many others from elsewhere, put them to the test, and summarised the results. The full write up is [here](https://www.empirical.ee/package-management-in-haskell/).

The pertinent summary of solutions is:

1. **Install globally**

   - You can still do global installs with `cabal install --lib the-package`.
2. **Use Stack as a run command**

   - You can use stack directly, eg: `stack exec --package containers --package optparse-generic [...and so on] -- runghc hello.hs`
3. **Create a Stack project**

   - The real deal. Run `stack new my-project hraftery/minimal`, put your code in `Main.hs` and your dependencies in `my-project.cabal` (and maybe `stack.yaml` - check the article), and then run `stack build` to automagically pull and build all dependencies.
4. **Use a Stack script**

   - Make your Haskell file itself an executable Stack script. Add `-- stack --resolver lts-6.25 script --package the-package` to the top of your `.hs` file and set its executable bit.

For my Edit/Test/Run workflow (eg. using VS Code, GHCi and GHC respectively), I found it pretty clear what works in practice. In summary:

1. Amongst a chorus of discouragement, **Global Installs** suit what I know of your use case just fine.
2. Where Global Installs don't make sense (eg. for managing dependency versions or being portable) **a Stack project** starting from my `minimal` template is a smooth transition to a more sophisticated and popular method.

Comment: `cabal install --lib` is discouraged because **a)** it _doesn't_ work reliably even in the moment (just look at all the questions that keep getting asked about it on SO) **b)** it's a good recipe for making your script impossible to run in the future without substantial package-versions archaeology work.

Comment: @leftaroundabout good to know. Better to know the pitfalls than to avoid out of fear. In that case, is it reasonable to use it in case it works and you're on your way, but if you hit headwinds then abandon it for one of the alternatives rather than brickwalling? Or is there damage in even trying it (other than developing a crutch)?

Comment: Well, I definitely wouldn't recommend it. _Especially_ when you're in a hurry you can't affort having inexplicable dependency problems crop up. That said, I myself still use Cabal in the deprecated v1 mode on one of my machines, where you globally install packages all the time. (It regularly leads to good old “Cabal hell”, but IMO that was never as bad a problem as people made it out to be.) But even then I generally add explicit dependencies to my scripts, so I _could_ easy reproduce their build later on.